# Why doesn't my code work for special cases?

Tags: c, primes

I wrote up a piece of code to find whether a number is prime or not and here it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter value for n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 3) {
        printf("It is a prime number");
    }
    for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            printf("It's not prime number \n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("It is a prime number \n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when my input is `33`, instead of the output printing `It's not a prime number`, since `33` is divisible by `3` and `11`, it prints that `It is a prime number`.

What is the problem with my code here?

Comment: You need to check all of the multiples before you can decide a number is prime. The else needs to be outside the loop and you'll need to set a flag inside the `if` so you can tell if it wasn't prime.

Comment: Just run your loop mentally for i = 2. What happens? What lines of code would be executed?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the first time the for loop is executed it immediately triggers either the if condition or else, then breaks, reaches the end and returns. The loop runs a total of 1 iteration max. Change to the following:

```
for (i = 2; i <= n / i; i++){
    if (n % i == 0){
        printf("It's not prime number \n");
        return 0;
    }
}
printf("It is a prime number \n");
```

Here the for runs correctly. It checks for all dividends, only then it's over and prints the false condition. Note you can optimize your code and only check up to the square root of n, because after that it can't hit true.

And add a return statement here, because the program is already over and doesn't need to continue:

```
if (n <= 1){
    printf("It's not a prime number");
    return 0;
}
if (n <= 3){
    printf("It is a prime number");
    return 0;
}
```

This also screens off 0, 1, and negative integers which are not prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right: you just have to make sure the program exits after having established whether a number is prime.

Also, you can stop the loop at `n/i`.

Last, but not least: `main` should return a `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int i,n;

    printf("Enter value for n: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 3){
        printf("It is a prime number\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 2; i < n/i; i++){
        if (n % i == 0){
            printf("It's not prime number \n");
            return 0;
        }
    }    
    printf("It is a prime number \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- `void main()` should be `int main()`
- you should check the return value of `scanf` and reject negative numbers
- `0` and `1` are not considered prime numbers.
- you should end the program if the number matches the first test.
- you output the result after a single test: it is correct if the test `if (n % i == 0)` is true as you have found a divisor, but if you have not, you should iterate, testing all possible divisors up to and including `floor(sqrt(n))`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter value for n: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("input error, not a number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("number should be positive: %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    if (n <= 1) {
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n", n);
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 2; i < n / i; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            printf("%d not prime number (divisible by %d)\n", n, i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d is a prime number\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try this:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
    int main(){
        int i,n;
        printf("Enter value for n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n <= 1){
            printf("It is a prime number");
        }
        for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++){
            if (n % i == 0){
                printf("It's not prime number \n");
                return 0;
            } 
            }
        printf("A prime Number");
        return 0;
    }
```

This is happening because in your code for `i = 3` and `n = 33`, `if` condition is failing which leads to `else` block directly and hence you are getting output as "It is a prime number".

Comment: I'd have upvoted your answer for the more efficient ```sqrt(n)``` limit. Even though it's possible for divisors to exist in the range ```[sqrt(n); n]```, if that happens there are also divisors in the range ```(0; sqrt(n))```, which would trigger the "non-prime" flagging anyway. Regrettably, your answer doesn't work in C, due to the inclusion of ```bits/stdc++.h```: the OP tagged only ```C```.

Comment: @picchiolu rest is just game of header files. You may add it according to your requirements. In C++, while tackling such programs its better to add every single header file so you don't stumble upon methods

Comment: Your sample does include a header that could be omitted and does not include a header that has to be there for the code to work (stdio.h)...

Comment: How  a header file could be omitted! It has to be there. What I meant to say is, you may add header files according to your wish. But if every now and then you don't want to find header file associated with a function, it's good to add some non - standard header files to save efforts!

Comment: I am trying to point out that your code, as it is currently written, does not compile.

Comment: Okay. Had some minor changes in it. And yes... Due to argued  `<bits/stdc++.h>` file, you have to use GCC otherwise it won't work :-)

Comment: You can get rid of that header by using ```i*i<=n``` as a condition ;)